# Does using Izanagi require the Mangekyo Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

Does using Izanagi require the Mangekyo Sharingan? I'm asking this question because on other questions, people are saying that the Izanagi and Izanami does not require the Mangekyo Sharingan, but rather, Senju and Uchiha DNA, plus a Sharingan. However, it is seen that many people used Izanagi without Senju and Uchiha DNA, as well as no Mangekyo Sharingan, but,
[image]

Black Zetsu's statement contradicts that entire argument.

So does using Izanagi really require a Mangekyo Sharingan? Or was this just a mistake?

Comment: P.S, that red circle is my mouse, I put it there to highlight the focus panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NO**, just like what you said, they only need a **Senju DNA** and a **Uchiha DNA**, plus a **Sharingan** which means genetic traits of the Sage of the Six Paths. The Uchiha, descended from the Sage, are able to perform Izanagi with their Sharingan.

You could check [HERE](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Izanagi) about Izanagi.

For Madara case, his Sharingan already upgraded to another level. So he have to use his MS(Mangekyo Sharingan) for the activation. But still, MS is from Sharingan. I see no error here.

However, could you list out who used Izanagi without about these condition?

> However, it is seen that many people used Izanagi without Senju and Uchiha DNA, as well as no Mangekyo Sharingan

Comment: Itachi used Izanami without Senju and Uchiha DNA. Danzo used Izanagi with the Sharingan in his arms that were in base form. But I don't see why Madara MUST use Izanagi with MS when he's still able to switch back to base Sharingan.

Comment: Itachi basically is an Uchiha, so he has the Uchiha DNA.
Danzo used Izanagi with help of the stolen sharingan and his arm(which is contain Hashirama cell also have senju DNA.)

Comment: As for why madara must use izanagi with MS when he's still able to switch back to base sharingan more like do you prefer drinking a hot water or a warm water. MS vs sharingan both is also sharingan. when you fullfil the requirement you can activate it.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I meant Itachi used Izanami without SENJU DNA. Idek why i typed Uchiha